# keep background music on my site even when changing pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

I try to insert background music on my site that doesn't change when you change page.

I tried with **getID3**, **javascript**, etc but without a solution.

```php
    <?php
    $mp3file = 'circle_of_life_whitesand.mp3';
    $skip = "0";
    SWFMovie :: streamMP3 ( mixed $mp3file [, float $skip= 0 ]): int

    $m = new SWFMovie();
    $m->setRate(12.0);
    $m->streamMp3(file_get_contents("circle_of_life_whitesand.mp3"));
// use your own MP3

// The file is 11.85 seconds at 12.0 fps = 142 frames
$m->setFrames(142);

header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
$m->output();
     ?>
```

Comment: The 90s called...

Comment: If you refresh the page, it will stop. There's nothing you can do about that. However, if you build your app as a SPA (single page app), the site won't reload when someone navigates to another page.

Comment: Have you considered using frames?

Comment: I would consider not using Flash (wich is [hardly supported anymore](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/)), but HTML5 Audio elements.